# flutter build web no me genera bien el index.html

Tags: web, flutter, dart

primero que todo, desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda, pasa y acontese lo siguiente, cree una app para android usando flutter, luego me solicitaron que sacará la versión web de esa misma aplicación, okey, activo el soporte web, luego hago el `flutter build web` y cuando voy a ver el index en build/web me aparece solo una pestaña en blanco cuando abro el archivo index.html, estoy haciendo algo mal, o es que es así o como funciona, necesito poder trabajar la versión web de la aplicación de manera local, debido a solicitud del dueño de la app que no quiere usar hosting ni nada de eso, además de que la usa solo para su negocio, y es de tipo, manejo de clientes y así, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida y reitero las gracias de antemano, Cabe mencionar que en el debug funciona a las mil maravillas.

Agregó el index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Blaxtor GYM">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>Blaxtor GYM</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y el código? ??

Comment: que necesitas ver exactamente

Comment: todo lo que crees que estés haciendo mal o tengas dudas. Sí un ejemplo de como estés haciendo las cosas no podremos ayudarte, tampoco somos adivinos para saber como tienes el código.

Comment: es que a ciencia cierta, no sé que podría mostrar, dado que la aplicación funciona perfectamente en el debug y en android, de hecho ya le genere el apk, es solo que me genera el index.html como una pagina en blanco, eso es lo que no entiendo

Comment: Y ejecutando el comando clean para limpiar y volver a darle build, ya lo probaste?

Comment: si, no cambio nada

Answer (score 0):

Un poco tarde, pero tuve el mismo problema y lo acabo de solucionar.

Primero que nada el código que muestras no es el build que realiza flutter, el build realizado lo encuentras en **`nombre_proyecto/build/web/index.html`**.
Segundo, el problema aquí es que si intentas abrir el build manualmente en el directorio no se va a poder, para eso debes ingresar `flutter run --release -d tuNavegador` desde la terminal de tu IDE como testeo.

Ya que tu programa corre correctamente puedes utilizar un hosting gratis, por ejemplo firebase Hosting, el cual es muy fácil de configurar y te proporciona un Hosting URL con el nombre de tu proyecto.

Espero ésta respuesta te ayude, en caso contrario aquí puedes encontrar más información al respecto https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/building

Saludos.